# Scrollable FrameLayout

Tags: android

Alright, so I followed the [Tab Widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial to create some tabs for my application.  In one of the tabs, I have a TextView with a lot of text that I'm debugging with.  But, with all of the text, all of the info doesn't show up on the screen.  I figured that I could scroll down to see the rest, but I cannot scroll.  Any idea on how to make it so that I can scroll down my FrameLayout so I can see the rest of my text?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can surround the view that you want to be scrollable with a ScrollView, as below:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff">

// the views here that you want to make scrollable

</ScrollView>
```