# Scrollable layout in FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scroll

I've a FrameLayout on my android app but I can't make to scrollable a part of this layout...I've tried some solutions to fix this problem, but I can't find a patch!
Pratically, I would like to see scrollable the linearlayout (maybe, linearlayout is not necessary) between Scrollview tags.

This is my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.robertot.timereport.com.robertot.timereport.Pages.YearlyStatFragment">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                // Some views to scroll

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnYearY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFilter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks!! :)

Comment: you can try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172742/scrollable-framelayout

Comment: thanks! it works but there's another problem: the last LinearLayout (id/bottom_linear) hide the scrollable views...How can I solve?? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a FrameLayout all the content views are one on top of the other, so the normal behaviour is that the Linear Layout hides part of the previous Scrollview. Why don't you use a LinearLayout or a Relative Layout instead of the FrameLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Fernando! I've solved my problem, as is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.robertot.timereport.com.robertot.timereport.Pages.YearlyStatFragment">



    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollyear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                //Some views

            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnYearY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFilter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can surround the view that you want to be scrollable with a ScrollView, as below:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff">

// the views here that you want to make scrollable

</ScrollView>
```